# Fake LinearLayout content on Design Tool with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Is there a way to fake the content of a LinearLayout (or any other layout) just for design purposes?

I have a LinearLayour inside an HorizontalScrollView. I add some ImageViews programmatically inside the LinearLayout because I get them from a web service. But I'd like to see the final output on the design view of the layout so I don't need to run the app every time I need to see some images there.

Is there a way, using the tools namespace (or any other trick) to show some ImageViews inside the LinearLayout only when using the design tools?

Comment: use isEditMode() to check if is in preview.So  you can write code in onDraw or onMeasure. like if(isInEditMode()){//your code return; } orignal code;

Comment: But he is asking for a way to see it at design time, so it cant involve any code...

Comment: it looks like what I need, thanks! can you add an answer? I'll try it and if it works I'll choose your answer as the accepted one